# ColdFusion Error: 503 (Remote CFC request timed out waiting to execute.)

Tags: coldfusion, iis-7, coldfusion-9, cfc, http-status-code-503

I am working on an application of ColdFusion 9 and IIS 7. The application was working fine but suddenly an error occurred on the page when a request was sent to a CFC page. Other CFM pages are working fine.

Here is the error message displayed in the Console.

> 503 (Remote CFC request timed out waiting to execute.)

Here is the message when I hit the same URL from a browser.

> The service is unavailable.

A few days ago I faced the same issue which I fixed by restarting but now it has happened again. I would like to permanently fix this issue.

Comment: Ajay - this error is the result of reaching your "simultaneous request limit" and your threads queuing causing the server to hang. To ask _why_ it happens is way to broad a question. I can happen for many reasons - networking, database locks, file i/o, basic hardware issues etc. You will need more clues. I suggest you monitor with fusion reactor and learn more about performance.

Comment: @MarkAKruger, Thank for the reply. i have checked the Worker Process of IIS Manager, there are only few requests. So the issue is not due to reaching "Simultaneous request limit".

Comment: What do your log files show?

Comment: You will not see it there Ajay - as I said you need JAVA introspection. The connector in fact does very little work and a few IIS worker process will not tell you what you need to know. You will need either the server monitor (a part of CF enterprise) or fusion reactor. They have a trial version. 

Also look at the *out.logs found in the runtime logs directory. You may find some clues there as to the initial issue. I'm not telling you something off the top of my head. I and 2 of my employees do this for a living all week long. :)